# What is the difference between the OpenCL functions length() and fast_length()?

Tags: performance, opencl, gpgpu

On page three of [this OpenCL reference sheet](http://r00tsecurity.org/db/cheat-sheets/Programming/OpenCL/opencl-quick-reference-card.pdf) (broken link) there are two built in vector length functions with identical parameters: `length()` and `half_length()`.

**What is the difference between these functions?** I gather from the name one is 'faster' than the other but in what circumstances? Does it sacrafice accuracy for this speed increase? If not, why would one ever use `length()` over `fast_length()`?

Comment: usually fast_ methods are routines that trade speed for accuracy.

Comment: Use an OpenCL reference instead.  You'll have little trouble discovering that fast_length uses half_sqrt which doesn't promise more than 10 bits of accuracy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the OpenCL spec (version 1.1, page 215):

- `float length(floatn p)`: Return the length of vector `p`, i.e. `sqrt(p.x²+p.y²+...)`
- `float fast_length(floatn p)`: Return the length of vector `p` computed as `half_sqrt(p.x²+p.y²+...)`

So `fast_length` uses `half_sqrt`, while `length` uses `sqrt`. As you can guess `sqrt` has better guarantees on accuracy, but might be slower. More to the point:

- Min Accuracy of `sqrt`: 3ulp (unit of least precision)
- Min Accuracy of `half_sqrt`: 8192ulp

  So `half_sqrt` can be about 11bits less accurate then `sqrt` (well actually it can be 13 bit less accurate, since there ist no requirement for `sqrt` not to be better then strictly necessary). Since `float` has a mantissa of `23bit` (plus one implicit bit) `half_sqrt` only promises about 10bit of precision (11bit including the implicit 1). It might however be faster, if the hardware has such a function. In hardware it's not unusual to have `sqrt` or `rsqrt` instruction providing only a small number of bits (like 10-14) and using Newton-Raphson iterations after the instruction to get the necessary precision. In such a case using `half_sqrt` is obviously faster.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the explanation of the difference in accuracy and the source, its those details that allow for an informed choice between them.